# NodeJS start ERROR in ./app/app.jsx Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs, npm-install

I am .net developer.Previous developer used nodeJS and react for one project.I must complete that project.That project use nodeJS,and reactJS.I installed NodeJS in windows 8

I install packages(npm install) it worked well.But now I try to run start project(npm start) but it give error about babel.

```
  C:\rc>npm start

> react-seed@0.0.13 prestart C:\rc
> npm install

npm WARN package.json react-seed@0.0.13 No license field.

> node-sass@3.4.2 install C:\rc\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js


> node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall C:\rc\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

` C:\rc\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node ` exists.
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\rimraf requires glob@'^7.0.0' but w
ill load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.15
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-decorators-l
egacy requires babel-runtime@'^6.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\babel-runtime,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.8.38
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015\node_modules\ba
bel-plugin-transform-regenerator requires babel-core@'^6.6.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.8.38
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\karma-mocha-reporter\node_modules\k
arma requires glob@'^7.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\rc\node_modules\glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.0.15

> react-seed@0.0.13 start C:\rc
> set NODE_ENV=development && node dev-server ./webpack/config

Listening at http://0.0.0.0:8000
Hash: dfc04e15fb6c36f0d4eb
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 812ms
           Asset       Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
vendor.bundle.js  839 bytes       0       vendor
js\app.0.0.13.js  102 bytes       1       app
chunk    {0} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 28 bytes [rendered]
    [0] multi vendor 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
chunk    {1} js\app.0.0.13.js (app) 28 bytes {0} [rendered]
    [0] multi app 28 bytes {1} [built] [1 error]

ERROR in ./app/app.jsx
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\rc\app\app.jsx: Unknown option:
direct.presets
    at Logger.error (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logge
r.js:58:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformat
ion\file\options\option-manager.js:126:29)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file
\options\option-manager.js:216:10)
    at File.initOptions (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\i
ndex.js:147:75)
    at new File (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:
137:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipe
line.js:164:16)
    at transpile (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:12:22)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:71:12)
 @ multi app

ERROR in ./app/vendor.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\rc\app\vendor.js: Unknown option
: direct.presets
    at Logger.error (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logge
r.js:58:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformat
ion\file\options\option-manager.js:126:29)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file
\options\option-manager.js:216:10)
    at File.initOptions (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\i
ndex.js:147:75)
    at new File (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:
137:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipe
line.js:164:16)
    at transpile (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:12:22)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\rc\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:71:12)
 @ multi vendor
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-seed",
  "version": "0.0.13",
  "description": "Seed project for React apps using ES6 & webpack.",
  "repository": "https://github.com/badsyntax/react-seed",
  "config": {
    "buildDir": "./build",
    "buildDirTests": "./build_tests",
    "devHost": "0.0.0.0",
    "devPort": 8000,
    "remoteHost": "https://mokey.gear.host"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production npm run webpack",
    "clean": "rimraf $npm_package_config_buildDir && mkdir $npm_package_config_buildDir",
    "env": "env",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx ./app ./webpack && echo No linting errors.",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "pretest": "npm install && npm run lint",
    "pretest-travis": "npm install && npm run lint",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development && node dev-server ./webpack/config",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma start --single-run",
    "test-dev": "NODE_ENV=test karma start",
    "test-travis": "NODE_ENV=test karma start --single-run",
    "webpack": "webpack --colors --progress --config ./webpack/config"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.1.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.4",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "intl": "^1.0.0",
    "intl-locales-supported": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.5",
    "ms-signalr-client": "^2.2.2",
    "normalize.css": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-flexgrid": "^0.7.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.0.0-rc-1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "superagent": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.1.11",
    "babel-core": "^5.3.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^3.1.23",
    "babel-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^0.1.8",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.3.3",
    "chai": "^2.3.0",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.12.1",
    "eslint": "^0.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^2.3.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.6",
    "html-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
    "karma-cli": "0.0.4",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.10",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-source-map-support": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "mocha": "^2.2.4",
    "mocha-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.0",
    "opn": "^1.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.7",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.3",
    "sass-loader": "^0.4.2",
    "sinon": "^1.14.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.2.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.2",
    "template-html-loader": "0.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.9.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "modules": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "globals": {
      "describe": true,
      "it": true,
      "xit": true,
      "xdescribe": true,
      "beforeEach": true,
      "sinon": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      "react"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "rules": {
      "strict": true,
      "indent": [
        2,
        2
      ],
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ],
      "new-cap": 0,
      "no-unused-expressions": 0,
      "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
      "react/display-name": 0,
      "react/jsx-quotes": 1,
      "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
      "react/jsx-sort-props": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
      "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
      "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
      "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
      "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
      "react/prop-types": 1,
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
      "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
      "react/wrap-multilines": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have configuration for Babel v6 (e.g. `presets` option) somewhere (`.babelrc`?) but you're using Babel v5.

Comment: how can I fix it?should I change package.json or install anything?Can you give me directive please.I am .net developer and in .net environment you can debug and handle everything but it nodejs that is problem

Comment: You need to choose a version and use the appropriate options / other packages for it. If possible go with v6 by updating any of your v5 Babel dependencies, like `babel-core`. Then make sure you have the configuration you need for v6. I don't know how you ended up with Babel v5 deps but v6 configuration.

Comment: what should I do.Search in google for install babel v6 ? or upgrade babel v5 to babel v6 ?

Comment: I think you have basic questions about Node / npm dependency management, so I'd suggest you start looking into info about that. Your `package.json` file has `dependency` and `devDependency` properties that specify package names and version ranges of things your project depends on. Right now you have `"babel-core": "^5.3.3"` which is Babel v5. So you need to update the version you depend on and `npm install`. If you need help with Babel specifically check out support resources here https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/README.md#looking-for-support. Someone may be able to help you on slack